# Did any sets have lots of 1x2 smooth tiles with gauges on them?

Tags: set-identification

[image]

[1x2 smooth tile with red 82 and yellow and white gauges pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3069bpx19#T=C)

I've inherited some LEGO and strangely it has 28 pieces of the above tile. Is there a set that uses a lot of these tiles?

I can't seem to find anything with more than 1 or 2 of them used.

Comment: The link you provided would be enough for me to consider it an authoritative answer.  They could have bought them from the wall of random bricks from a LEGO store or gotten a batch from BrickLink or a vendor at a LEGO convention.

Comment: Not sure how I managed to add that link - I thought I'd just copied the description that was with the picture I found on the net!

Comment: I will wade through the list that the link provided,  the lot I have seems to be lots of bits of incomplete sets so I'm trying to unravel each mystery. I'm inclined to think the 28 pieces are part of a set, as most of the other bits seem to form sets. But you could be right, might be a random lot. I just hoped someone would recognise such a large number of those pieces as conspicuously part of a certain set. Thanks for your comments anyway

Comment: @David C; I have edited your question and added the link

Answer (score 1):

No. :)

I checked several "gauges pattern" tiles. There is no set with more than 3 of them.